# Create a "sequence of sequence" ldap.controls.RequestControl object

Tags: ldap, asn.1, python-ldap

I use python-ldap to search an ActiveDirectory as if it was any regular LDAP server. It works, SSL, authentication and everything.

Now I want to use the [server side sort request control defined in RFC 2891](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2891#section-1.1), which has the OID `1.2.840.113556.1.4.473`.

Python-ldap does not support that control out of the box, so I must create it myself. I did this :

```
server_side_sort = ldap.controls.RequestControl('1.2.840.113556.1.4.473', True)
```

But I don't know how to compute the `encodedControlValue` parameter, which is [the BER-encoded ASN.1 control value](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap-controls.html#classes).

I see that `pyasn1` has many parts to comptue it, like `univ.SequenceOf`, `univ.Sequence` and `univ.Boolean`. Looking at the [RFC2251 module of pyasn1](http://pyasn1.sourceforge.net/rfc2251.html), I came up with this :

```
class LDAPString(univ.OctetString): pass

class AttributeDescription(LDAPString): pass

class MatchingRuleId(LDAPString): pass

class ServerSideSortOnName(univ.Sequence):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
        namedtype.NamedType('attributeDesc', AttributeDescription('name')), 
        namedtype.NamedType('reverseOrder', univ.Boolean(False)) )

class ServerSideSortControl(univ.SequenceOf):
     componentType = ServerSideSortOnName()

sss = ServerSideSortControl()

serversidesort = ldap.controls.RequestControl('1.2.840.113556.1.4.473',True,sss)
```

Name might not be indexed, I know. I thought it could help debugging to match the [base64 value shown on this MSDN snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813639%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But when I add this control (which might not even be valid) to ldap.search_ext, I get the error `TypeError: ('expected a string', ServerSideSortControl())`

How can I create a server side sort control value on attribute `name` that python-ldap `ldap.search_ext` will accept, using pyasn1 or similar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to nest `univ.Sequence` in `univ.SequenceOf` and implement `encodeControlValue` that returns the BER encoded control the server expect.

```
class SSSRequest(univ.SequenceOf):
    componentType = univ.Sequence()

class SSSRequestSequence(univ.Sequence):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
        namedtype.NamedType('attributeType', univ.OctetString()),
    )

class SSS_CONTROL_REQUEST(LDAPControl):
    def __init__(self,controlType,criticality,controlValue=None,encodedControlValue=None):
        LDAPControl.__init__(self,controlType,criticality,controlValue,encodedControlValue)

    def encodeControlValue(self):
        sss = SSSRequest()

        for k in self.controlValue:
            Skey = SSSRequestSequence()
            Skey.setComponentByName('attributeType', k)
            sss.setComponentByPosition(0, Skey)
        return encoder.encode(sss)

    def decodeControlValue(self,encodedValue):
        sssr = decoder.decode(encodedValue)[0]
        rsp = SSSResponse()
        for n, v in enumerate(sssr):
            try:
                rsp.setComponentByPosition(n, int(v))
            except Exception, e:
                print str(e)
        if rsp.success:
            return True
        return rsp.error

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SSSREQUEST_OID = '1.2.840.113556.1.4.473'
    sss = SSS_CONTROL_REQUEST(SSSREQUEST_OID, False, ['cn'])
    srv = ldap.open('localhost')
    srv.simple_bind_s()
    id = srv.search_ext('ou=people,dc=example,dc=com', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filterstr='(objectClass=user)', serverctrls=[sss])
    print srv.result3(id)
```

Implementing reverse order sort is left as an exercice ;)

The code was tested successfully with a AD-LDS instance running on Windows Server 2008 R2, 64 bits (but you have to make the bind non-anonymous).

Comment: Thanks ! Your original code did not run as-is. I updated it with one that works on my machine.